# CoordinatorLayout with full screen background image

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

[image]

I tried to get this result by CoordinatorLayout but unable to set fullscreen image on background which expand on whole screen same like in image. I tried several ways like putting `LinearLayout` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but not getting close to layout what i want to get.

I tried several way to achieve this but not getting anywhere.please help

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:id="@+id/viewuserProfileMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        android:src="@drawable/baby"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/diagonal_cut_layerlist">

                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:background="@color/primary"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you want to collapse your layout too ?

Comment: yes with circle image too

Comment: Please check my answer and do it that way it will be easy for you to handle multiple layers of the required layout.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is make `another layout` set it's `background color` and have another `RelativeLayout` in that. Then **`include`** you current layout into that one and it will be easy to handle for you.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:id="@+id/viewuserProfileMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <include layout="@layout/yourCurrentLayout except it's background"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: will update you soon with result.Thanks Umair for your help

Comment: Do i need to create one more CoordinatorLayout inside relative layout

Comment: @Ritu it's not necessary, but if your requirements say so then yes you can do it. But it will be good if you make another CoordinatorLayout in your included layout file.

Comment: i will try your suggestion then let you know with result. Thanks

Comment: sure no problem.

Comment: please check i update my code i am not able to get that view, setting `android:layout_margin="20dp` make gap which not as my requirement.

Comment: @Ritu if it's the problem of layout_margin you can increase or decrease it too. I just gave you the idea how to put it :)

Comment: but Umair i am not getting close to above layout, actually above image confuse me alot, Can you give me bit more help in this